# Equivalent C# LINQ code for SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, group-by

c.I am new to LINQ and have the below SQL code which I would like an equivalent C# LINQ

```
SELECT
    COUNT(c.sId)
    ,a.Activity
FROM FillStat c
INNER JOIN Activity a
    ON a.Id = c.ActivityID
WHERE c.pId= 300
GROUP BY a.Activity
```

Comment: Which table does `pId` belong too?

Comment: @juharr It belongs to FillStat

Comment: `var results = from c in db.FillStat from a in c.Activities where c.pId = 300 group c.sId by a.Activity into grp select new { Activity = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()}`

Comment: biggest difference is select is the last thing in Linq instead of the first, which makes much more sense to me. I suggest looking up general concepts of list comprehensions and map / reduce especially if you want to apply what you've learned to other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using query syntax it will look like this:

```
var result = from c in db.FillStat
             join a in db.Activity on c.ActivityID equals a.Id
             where c.pId = 300
             group 1 by a.Activity into g
             select new {
                 Activity = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```